# CLLocationManager not returning location after temporarily disabling in settings

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cllocationmanager

I temporarily disabled the location services, and the permissions for my app, so that I could test some code which dealt with the scenario where they're not available. Upon turning them on again, my location now can't be fetched, using this code:

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
CLLocation *currentLocation = locationManager.location;
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

The `locationManager.location` is equal to `nil` after running this code.

I'm running this on an iPad running iOS 6.

Comment: It's a bit unclear whether you're using the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` or you're just using the `locationManager.location` property

Comment: I'm not using the delegate.

Comment: I never used CLLocationManager without delegate, but I assume it could be possible that if you switched off the location services then the `location` property could be nil. That's why the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` exists. Also to give the `CLLocationManager` the time to retrieve a location. Moreover sometimes the first `location` returned could be old, so I'd just change that code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the delegate for CLLocationManager

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Try the delegates of CLLocationManager.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    self.currentLocation = newLocation;            
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // The location "unknown" error simply means the manager is currently unable to get the location.
    // We can ignore this error for the scenario of getting a single location fix, because we already have a
    // timeout that will stop the location manager to save power.
    if ([error code] != kCLErrorLocationUnknown) {
        [self stopUpdatingLocation:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"Error")];
    }
}
```